# C++ type based caching without using static storage

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I'm using something like:

```
struct VectorCache
{
    template<typename T>
    std::vector<T>& GetTs()
    {
        static std::vector<T> ts;
        return ts;
    }
};
```

to create/access some vectors based on the contained type. This works fine as long as I have only one object of type `VectorCache`, but when I use multiple objects I will get same vectors from all instances of `VectorCache` as the vectors are static variables.

I tried to move the vectors as member variables using something similar to `boost::any` and access them using `std::type_index` of T, but this is somehow slower than the direct access I used before.

Another options is to transform `struct VectorCache` to something like `template<int index> struct VectorCache`, but the problem is still there - I will have to be careful to have only one instance/index to have correct behaviour.

**Is it possible to access the vectors directly based on `T` and also have the caching instance based instead of class based?**

Comment: And I guess you don't want `VectorCache<T>` (i.e. move `template<typename T>` from the function to the class), right? Because then the member variable is simple.

Comment: Boost.Any is essentially the idea behind any solution. If that's too slow, I wonder if any other solution will be sufficiently fast. A map with `std::type_index` key certainly comes to mind.

Comment: Will `VectorCache` usage appear in multiple files?  If not, a convention to instantiate `template<int index> struct VectorCache` with `__LINE__` is a common, effective, dirty little hack that can be eased with a macro.

Comment: why are you using a static rather than an object on the heap generated by a factory pattern approach?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  This looks like an implementation detail that is causing you problems along the chosen route you took to what you are really trying to do.

Comment: @Yakk I'm trying to find the best possible solution for the problem described in the question - find a way to get type dependent vector in O(1) without making the vector static. It is more of a theoretical problem. The solution proposed by Kerrek is good enough for any real world program.

Answer (score 5):

You could try an unchecked analogue of Boost.Any. See if that's fast enough for you (though I don't believe it would make a big difference):

```
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeindex>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

class AnyCache
{
    struct TEBase
    {
        virtual ~TEBase() {}
        virtual void * get() = 0;
    };

    template <typename T> struct TEObject : TEBase
    {
        T obj;
        virtual void * get() override { return static_cast<void *>(&obj); }
    };

    std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::unique_ptr<TEBase>> cache;

public:
    AnyCache(AnyCache const &) = delete;
    AnyCache & Operator=(AnyCache const &) = delete;

    template <typename T> decltype(auto) get()
    {
        using U = std::decay_t<T>;
        using C = std::vector<U>;

        std::unique_ptr<TEBase> & p = cache[typeid(U)];
        if (!p) { p = std::make_unique<TEObject<C>>(); }
        return *static_cast<C *>(p->get());
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
AnyCache ac;
ac.get<int>().push_back(20);
ac.get<std::string>().push_back("Hello");
for (auto const & x : ac.get<Foo>()) { std::cout << x << '\n'; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - the part I was thinking as "slow" was not the implementation of boost::any (I was using something similar, not boost::any), it was the search in the map/unordered_map

Answer (score 2):

If - and it's a big if - your `VectorCache`-using code isn't threaded, you can do this:

```
struct VectorCache
{
    VectorCache() : instance_counter_(++s_instance_counter_) { }

    template<typename T>
    std::vector<T>& GetTs()
    {
        static std::vector<std::vector<T>> tss;
        if (tss.size() <= instance_counter_)
            tss.resize(instance_counter_);
        return tss[instance_counter_];
    }

    size_t instance_counter_;
    static size_t s_instance_counter_;
};

// and define size_t VectorCache::s_instance_counter_;
```

[implementation on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/ByJZ1y)

With a little synchronisation you can make it thread safe, or even thread specific if that suits.  Add deletion of copy construction / assignment etc. if that makes sense in your intended usage.

Comment: And pray that nobody is storing references to those vectors?

Comment: @KerrekSB: lots of data has iterator or pointer invalidation characteristics - you need to understand them and see if they're suitable for your intended client code, not pray ;-P. Sure there are extra things you can do if necessary, but I'm not going to broaden this answer arbitrarily on that specific supposed need, especially when successful use of the code posted in the question suggests that isn't an actual problem.